# rails sending the wrong content-type in ajax response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

I have been struggling terribly for the better part of the day with the following problem:

- I have a rails 3.1 app - running fine
- I am trying to add some ajax to it

However, no matter what I try, Rails insists on sending the wrong content-type in the response header.

```
#the form    
= form_for @signup, :url => '/signup', :remote => true do |f|
    = f.text_field :email, :class => 'email', :size => 26
    = f.submit 'Notify me'

#In the controller
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :content_type => 'text/javascript', :layout => false}
  end
end

#the JS file: create.js.erb
alert('HI!');
```

This is not working, while I think it should. Inspecting the server response with Firebug it tells me the response header has a content-type of `text/html`. I figure this is why it isn't working (as on a newly generated app, using the same jquery-rails gem it responds with a `text/javascript` header.

The server *says* it's responding with JS:

```
Processing by SignupsController#create as JS
```

But is somehow refusing to send the correct header. I am lost on where to look next.

Any help or direction as to where to look next would be greatly appreciated!
Erwin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok found the solution,

So an after_filter in application controller was overriding the content-type. And they are processed inside out. So it was overwriting my declarations.

Comment: Thanks!  This sent me down the right path.  An after filter in the app was setting headers['Content-Type'] explicitly to text/html.  Because of this, I was unable to set the content_type in the respond_to block the usual way.  I was able to overwrite it by calling headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/javascript' in the respond to block.