# Rails 3.2 .js.erb renders but never fires

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having a very confusing problem. I've done this before, but can't figure out why it wouldn't be working in this case, and I'd appreciate anyone who might have any idea where to start looking.

```
# app/views/petitions/new
<%= form_for @petition, :remote => true do |form| %>
  <%= form.submit "Submit", :class => "primary" %>
<% end %>


# app/controllers/petitions_controller       
def create
  # I've stripped everything out of here to isolate the issue
end

# app/views/petitions/create.js.erb
alert("Hello World");

# log
Started POST "/petitions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-02 23:07:43 -0500
Processing by PetitionsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bWXmagSz0hVqhQ1/1U480kQUYcIhmSEbNMAofWYT2Oc=", "petition"=>{"name"=>"", "email"=>"", "location"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered petitions/create.js.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_activity_at` = '2012-02-03 04:07:43' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

The "alert()" never fires, nor does anything else I put into the `.js.erb` view, even though the log says `Rendered petitions/create.js.erb (0.0ms)`. I've done this before in other (non 3.2) projects, so I'm convinced that I'm doing something glaringly stupid or there is something very sneaky happening here.

---

*UPDATE* - Firebug seems to be telling me that I'm receiving a content type of "text/html" rather than "text/javascript". I'm still not sure why this is happening or where to start looking for the cause, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're in a dev environment, sprockets will automatically load all the js files you've required. Have a look at your resources in the browser and see if create.js is getting loaded.

Comment: Open firebug and watch the response.Because even single syntax error in js response will stop the script being executed at the browser.

Comment: Nope, I just checked and it doesn't seem to be grabbing it.

Comment: I have watched the console in Firebug, and nothing appears to be broken.

Comment: Firebug is telling me the Content-type is "text/html; charset=utf-8" , that can't be right?

Comment: Yeah, I figured this out, did exactly the same thing as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482742/rails-sending-the-wrong-content-type-in-ajax-response

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following line at the top of your `PetitionsController`:

```
respond_to :js, :only => :create
```